# jquery: trim off the last part of an url

Tags: jquery, path, location, trim

I have these URLs,

```
http://mysite.net/home
http://mysite.net/projects
http://mysite.net/links
```

And I want to trim off home, projects, links ect, so I only have this http://mysite.net/

But it should not trim anything off if I have this in the URL http://mysite.net/

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var domain = window.location.protocol + window.location.port + "//" + window.location.hostname;
```

should do it.

**Edit:** Whoops, missed slashes :-)

Comment: Works well, assuming the `url` to modify is actually the current `window.location`

Comment: @Niklas Yes, a _very_ good point. I just assumed the `url` in the question to mean that the OP needed the current location trimming.

Comment: Could well be, he didn't say it wouldn't be, he just didn't  say it would be either...

Answer (score 2):

just pick up location.origin in javascript, nothing to do with jquery

Comment: Is this a Chrome specific field? I can't get it to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var path = "http://mysite.net/projects";
var pathComponents = path.split('/');

var protocol = pathComponents[0];
var domain = pathComponents[2];
```

I'm assuming here that you're not just getting the domain of the current website and what you're after is a result based on a string (possible of another website).

Answer (score 1):

If url is a pure string instead of 'windows.location', you could use a simple regex to do this

```
function get_domain(url) {
    return url.match(/http:\/\/.*?\//)[0];
}
```

Comment: isn't he going to supply window.location for the url attribute? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `substring` and `indexOf`:

```
url.substring(0,url.substring(7).indexOf("/")+8);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/HcUhj/

Comment: nope substring and substr are a bit funny when it comes to cross browser (i think in my opinion)

Comment: @Val I am not using `substr` and as far as `substring` is concerned, it is cross browser supported, if you use it appropriately.

Comment: I know im just saying I run into some trouble once, it was working very well until one day it's just was the wrong way to go on about it, although it is great but it is not reliable [in my opinion] n I wish I had a copy of my problem back then :)